# Unity SetActive(true) not working for panel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a finishMenu that I'd like to activate when the player finishes the level. I have a UI container (canvas) that contains among other things, my finishMenu. When colliding with a finish pad, the player script executes EndLevel(). It executes a lot of stuff, but it also calls the Finish() function on my UI container:

```
    public void Finish()
    {
        Debug.Log("Finish Called!");
        finishMenu.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log("self: " + finishMenu.activeSelf + " hierarchy: " + finishMenu.activeInHierarchy);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }
```

this is supposed to set it to active, and I'm not getting any errors. The second Debug.Log tells me that finishMenu is activeSelf but not activeInHierarchy, even though the parent gameObject (UI container) is active...
[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MCLu.png)
I have assigned finishMenu in the inspector, so I don't know what to do...

I have tried debugging with the Debug.Logs and breakpoints, and searching through my code to see if something is setting it to inactive, but I haven't found the answer yet. The finishMenu is supposed to activate, but it doesn't activate.

Comment: Pausing the game the same frame you are setting it active may be the problem. Try delaying the pausing to the next frame and see if it works

Comment: @Jichael I have tried to remove "Time.timeScale = 0f;" but it didn't solve the problem. I have a pause menu that works perfectly fine and also pauses the game. Thanks anyways

Comment: Are you sure you are activating the finish menu pannel, not the finish menu object / script?

Comment: @Jay finishMenu is declared as a GameObject, and using .SetActive(true), it should activate. The finishMenu panel is a GameObject

Comment: Please show us all of the relavent code or it will be difficult to help :)

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSelf` measn your call to `SetActive` was successful, but that will only set the `ActiveSelf` flag on that one local object, it will not actually become active until `ActiveInHirearchy` is true.

The fact that it is not `ActiveInHirearchy` has only one possible cause: That one or more of the object's transform parents is not active.

`ActiveInHirearchy` is true when and only when an object *and all of its parents* are `ActiveSelf`.

From your image, it looks like you need to set the `gameObject` which is called `FinnishMenuPannel` to active as well, setting any of its children will not do this, you have to set it on the `gameObject` itself.